# Hiding sub-folders with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

If I have a website (www.domain.com)

In the root I have an index.php file that redirects the site to www.domain.com/folder-1/folder-2/

How can i use .htaccess to hide folder-1/folder-2/ from the URL in the address bar?

(Moving the site files from folder-2 to the root of the site isn't an option.)

Ive tried this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(/folder-1/folder-2)
RewriteRule (.*) /folder-1/folder-2$1
```

but i get this error:

```
This page isn’t working
domain.com redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

Ive also tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$   /folder-1/folder-2/$1
```

But it doesn't have any affect at all

And ive also tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^folder-1/folder-2$ /?&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

But it doesnt have any affect at all

Comment: Aren't these "sub-folders" required to route the URL? You want the URL to appear without any URL-path at all?!

Comment: Thats correct - if at all possible? (Without IFrames, but thats all i can think of right now)

Comment: ***(Without IFrames and spoofing, but thats all i can think of right now) - im unsure if my understanding of .htaccess rewrites is wrong or not...

Comment: "In the root I have an index.php file that redirects the site to www.domain.com/folder-1/folder-2/" - You wouldn't use .htaccess to "fix" the URL that you are already linking to. You should already link to the _canonical_ URL. But aren't `example.com/` (your "homepage") and `example.com/` (that should point to `example.com/folder-1/folder-2/`) 2 different pages? You can't have two different pages on the _same_ URL. Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Quoted from https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204643270/using-htaccess-rewrite-rules … "Direct requests for one subdirectory to a different subdirectory or the primary directory (document root) Example: example.com/folder1 becomes example.com/folder2 or just example.com. "


This is essentially what im trying to achieve but not 100% sure about how to go about it

Comment: `!^/(/folder-1/folder-2)` – that pattern would demand that the requested URI not start with `//folder-1/…` - which it _never_ does, so this condition won’t _ever_ prevent the following rewrite. Why _any_ capturing groups here at all? `!^/folder-1/folder-2`

Answer (score 0):

> Quoted from mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204643270/… … "Direct requests for one subdirectory to a different subdirectory or the primary directory (document root) Example: example.com/folder1 becomes example.com/folder2 or just example.com."

Yes, that is what URL rewriting does, however....

> 1. In the root I have an `index.php` file that redirects the site to `www.example.com/folder-1/folder-2/`
> 2. How can i use `.htaccess` to **hide `folder-1/folder-2/`** from the URL in the address bar?

This is a contradiction. In order to "hide" `/folder-1/folder-2/` from the address bar you would need to redirect the request back to the root again! Which, needless to say, doesn't make a whole lot of sense (apart from being "impossible").

With URL rewriting you can internally rewrite the request from `/folder-1/folder-2/` back to the root (or rather, back to `index.php` in the root). But this doesn't "hide" anything.

For example, to rewrite the request `/folder-1/folder-2/` (exactly as stated) back to `/index.php` in the document root then you would do something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^folder-1/folder-2/$ /index.php [L]
```

The requested URL `/folder-1/folder-2/` remains in the browser's address bar. It is not "hidden".

The directives you've posted imply you have requests of the form `/folder-1/folder-2/<something>` - however, you've not stated this in your question description?

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(/folder-1/folder-2)
> RewriteRule (.*) /folder-1/folder-2$1
> ```

The directives you've posted attempt to do the complete opposite and rewrite the request from the root to the `/folder-1/folder-2` - maybe this is what you do really want to do? However, this will also bypass the "`index.php` file that redirects the site to `www.example.com/folder-1/folder-2/`" (as stated in #1 above). These two actions conflict.

To internally rewrite all requests for URLs directly in the document root to `/folder-1/folder-2/` then you would do something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

Rewrite ^([^/]+)$ /folder-1/folder-2/$1 [L]
```

This assumes that the URLs being requested are of the form `/<file>`, where `<file>` is only 1 path depth. ie. not `/<dir>/<file>`. This is what prevents a rewrite loop in this instance.

Comment: Ill try to clarify what im trying to do. 

The reason for index.php in the root is to force users to /folder-1/folder-2/ - essentially what id like to do is sack off the index.php all together, and when people visit domain.com it just shows the contents of /folder-1/folder-2/ - without them seeing /folder-1/folder-2/ in the address bar

Comment: I "Could" create a php file that "Includes" the page from /folder-1/folder-2/ but my issue is that would then break any html/css relative links - i wanted to try with .htaccess to see if that would be a good work around.

Comment: I could also move all of the contents from /folder-1/folder-2/ to the route however theres another part of the system sat in the route folder and i dont want this i the same folder as the site files.

Comment: If this isnt possible to do (I dont know if it is or isnt) then my next plan is to setup two subdomain. One aimed at /folder-1/folder-2/ and the other subdomain aimed at the other folder i mentioned above.

Comment: "what id like to do is sack off the index.php all together, and when people visit domain.com it just shows the contents of /folder-1/folder-2/ - without them seeing /folder-1/folder-2/" - Ok, the second part of my answer covers that. However, if you have relative links in your HTML source then you could end up with the same problems (as the PHP include) - it may depend where these "relative" links are intended to go. (If you are doing any kind of URL rewriting then you generally need to avoid relative links.) The above rewrites _everything_, CSS and all, so see how it goes.

Comment: "however theres another part of the system sat in the route folder" - You now have to be careful of conflicts. The above is rewriting any direct requests to the root folder to the `/folder-1/folder-2/` directory, which is naturally going to render any files in the root inaccessible. Unless you can be more specific and only target the requests to be rewritten (or not - whichever is easier).